# Ошибка got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop при выполнении prefetch_related в tortoise

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, async-await, асинхронность

Есть асинхронный запрос запрос, он находится в асинхронной функции `async def get_document`

```
packages = await Package.filter(document_id=str(document.uuid), parent_id=None).prefetch_related(
            'goods',
            'childs',
            'childs__goods',
            'package_barcodes',
            'package_barcodes__goods',
            'childs__childs',
            'childs__childs__goods',
            'childs__package_barcodes',
            'childs__package_barcodes__goods',
            'childs__childs__package_barcodes',
            'childs__childs__package_barcodes__goods'
        )
```

При выполнении функции `get_document` в event_loop (т.е. в `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`) всё работает нормально, я получаю все связанные объекты. Но при выполнении этой же функции из вновь созданного цикла (`new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()`) падает ошибка указанная в заголовке поста. `new_loop` создаётся и запускается в отдельном потоке. Причем если в `prefetch_related` я буду запрашивать только один тип начального пути (только `goods` или только `childs` или `childs__childs, childs__childs__goods, childs__childs__package_barcodes__goods`), то всё работает без ошибок. Не могу понять в чём проблема

Answer (score 0):

Я передал в поток изначальный `event_loop` (`event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`), уже внутри потока создал task и передал туда асинхронную функцию (внутри потока `task = event_loop.create_task(get_document())`), и всё заработало. Но я всё так и не пойму почему я мог из вновь созданного цикла событий запрашивать в `prefetch_related` только один тип начального пути.